Do we want some more specific tags on Coggy?
In response to Jeromy's answer here https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/a/724/3543;
I thought it might be a good idea to start a post for people to post tags they think we should have and the synonym, if any, so we can have a vote.
One tag suggestion per post.

If you see a cluster of, say, 5-6 questions that need retagging, you can probably just post it here.  Otherwise we're putting the cart before the horse.

@ChuckSherrington it was Jeromy's idea.. did you see his post? in the link? in the Q I didn't want to make the individual suggestions, I thought I'd leave that up to Jeromy and you guys, but yup if we have a few Q for a tag, we can just create one hey?

You can let the retags bump the posts and let the front page do the vetting of the edits, too.  I think the issue in the past was more doing 25 at a time, not that there was retagging going on.  I'll keep an eye out for things that might need the tags, though.

@ChuckSherrington good thinking 99

A recent question from @tinnire initially said, 

"PS. Someone add a tag for MEG (magnetoencephalography) please."

I created meg, but haven't filled out the tag wiki yet, and @ArtemKaznatcheev added neurobiology instead of meg to tinnire's question. If meg is undesirable, vote this answer down and consider removing the dedicated tag or adding it as a synonym for one of the broader tags. Otherwise, if it gets voted up, I'll fill in the tag wiki if no one else does (I have no experience with or real knowledge of MEG). I wouldn't recommend eeg as a synonym, but the broader neuroimaging would work if a tag that is more specific is not useful. At present, a search for "MEG" produces eight results, but these are mostly answers, not OPs that mention MEG specifically.
